# People Search on root site

Tags: web-part, search

I am trying to get people search setup on our root site, but i'm not sure how to link the people search box webpart to the People search core results web part on the same page.

When I drop both parts onto a page, and do a  search the results page is re-directed to the enterprise search page instead of the local page with the core results part one.

The search is working and returning results, just on the wrong page.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the "Target search results page URL" in the Miscellaneous section of the properties on the Search box webpart